# How to access variable from razor to razor in .net maui blazor

Tags: c#, razor, maui-blazor

In my shared folder, I have 4 razor files.

> TopNavBar.razor
>
> Sidebar.razor
>
> MainLayout.razor
>
> Footer.razor

[image]

Inside `MainLayout.razor` I have this code

```
 @inherits LayoutComponentBase

<Sidebar/>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <TopNavBar/>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    @Body
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
        <a class="border rounded d-inline scroll-to-top" href="#page-top"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
```

Inside my `Sidebar.razor` I have this toggle button and the c# code

```
<button @onclick=toggleButton class="btn rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle" type="button"></button>



@code {
    private string toggled = "";

    private void toggleButton() {
        if (toggled == "")
            toggled = "toggled";
            else 
            toggled = "";
    }
}
```

In some cases, I also need to change the class of `<div></div>` element in `TopNavBar.razor` when the toggle button is click.

The question is, How to change the Html tags inside one.razor from two.razor? or how to access variables from razor to razor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this function by passing data with `Component parameters` between components.

Component parameters pass data to components and are defined using public `C# properties` on the component class with the `[Parameter]` attribute.

You can refer to the sample code:

```
public class PanelBody
{
    public string? Text { get; set; }
    public string? Style { get; set; }
}

<div class="card w-25" style="margin-bottom:15px">
    <div class="card-header font-weight-bold">@Title</div>
    <div class="card-body" style="font-style:@Body.Style">
        @Body.Text
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "Set By Child";

    [Parameter]
    public PanelBody Body { get; set; } =
        new()
        {
            Text = "Set by child.",
            Style = "normal"
        };
}
```

For more, you can check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bind-across-more-than-two-components

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#component-parameters .

Comment: Thanks. It's helped me a lot to understand t flow.